# Is there a way in Azure to automate the creation of an authorized_keys file with multiple keys?

Tags: linux, powershell, azure

Our team is using Azure PowerShell to create and initialize Linux VMs. I'm not at all familiar with Azure, but trying to help someone else set this up. Is there a way to provide a custom authorized_keys file and have Azure PowerShell drop it in ~/.ssh? We want this to occur automatically upon creation.

Comment: You can use the custom script extension to copy the file to the VM upon creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @modo has mentioned in comment, you are able to use "[custom script extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript)" to achieve this goal.

If you are using ARM VM:

```
$RGName = '<resource-group-name>'
$VmName = '<vm-name>'
$Location = '<location>'

$ExtensionName = 'CustomScriptForLinux'
$Publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'
$Version = '<version>'

$PublicConf = '{
    "fileUris": ["<url>"],
    "commandToExecute": "<command>"
}'
$PrivateConf = '{
    "storageAccountName": "<storage-account-name>",
    "storageAccountKey": "<storage-account-key>"
}'

Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMName $VmName -Location $Location `
  -Name $ExtensionName -Publisher $Publisher `
  -ExtensionType $ExtensionName -TypeHandlerVersion $Version `
  -Settingstring $PublicConf -ProtectedSettingString $PrivateConf
```

If you are using ASM VM:

```
$VmName = '<vm-name>'
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $VmName -Name $VmName

$ExtensionName = 'CustomScriptForLinux'
$Publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'
$Version = '<version>'

$PublicConf = '{
    "fileUris": ["<url>"],
    "commandToExecute": "<command>"
}'
$PrivateConf = '{
    "storageAccountName": "<storage-account-name>",
    "storageAccountKey": "<storage-account-key>"
}'

Set-AzureVMExtension -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -VM $vm `
  -Publisher $Publisher -Version $Version `
  -PrivateConfiguration $PrivateConf -PublicConfiguration $PublicConf |
  Update-AzureVM
```